# use change() to detect changes of attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible? I want to detect the width of a div for example, bind it with on() to do something..

```
var widthVal= $('#panel').width();

$(widthVal).on('change', function(){

});
```

then I create a button to increase the width of the #panel, but nothing happen..

use change() to detect changes of attribute value ? make sense?

Comment: how automatically the div will change .Some event will occur and div will change u have to write the code here

Comment: You can optionally look into [DOM Mutation Observers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to use [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent).

However, they have been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) and are not widely supported.

I think your best bet is to use a timer to periodically check if the CSS attribute has changed;

```
var $panel = $('#panel');
var width = $panel.width();

$panel.on('resized', function () {
  // do something!
});

setInterval(function () {
  if ($panel.width() !== width) $panel.trigger('resized');
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use the following approach http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/5PXnv/

HTML

```
<div>test</div>
```

JS

```
var changeWidth = function(el, width) {
    el.css("width", width + "px");
    el.trigger("width-changed");
}
var div = $("div");
div.on("width-changed", function() {
    console.log("changed");
});
setTimeout(function() {
    changeWidth(div, 200);
}, 1000);
```